# Retrieving and inserting data in custom fields

Tags: custom-field, database

I need a *form* which will allow user to add data like name,phone number and email address .This data will be submitted to **custom fields** i have created using **Advanced Custom Fields**.I have no idea how do we insert data from form to custom fields.I heard about **wpdb** which allows safe connection to the database.

The screenshot have a **service** custom post type with title and and description to add . What i need to do is create a form and add data using **wpdb**

Glad if anyone could help me to insert data in custom fields.
[image: service custom post type]

Comment: you want to add data to which object ? to use them where ? what have your tried now ?

Comment: @mmm i edited my question . is that clear now ?

Comment: I'm assuming by "form" you mean some type of form on the frontend that users can submit, that would then be set in the new post (or service)?  If you setup ACF correctly it will already show the custom fields in another meta box.  Please provide more specific details, your limited information provided is not enough to even know what you're trying to do ...

Comment: hello @sMyles , yes i need a form at  a front end which submit data and saves it to the custom fields in 'service' post type . you described exactly what it needed